# Angular: Lazy loading backgroundimage in Angular

Tags: angular

I Angular have a grid with 1000+ backgroundimages. I want to lazy load them on scroll. This is my code:

```
<div inViewport [inViewportOptions]="{ threshold: [0] }" (inViewportAction)="onIntersection($event)" class="artist_image" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(\''+ artist.image + '\')'}"></div>
```

```
 public onIntersection({
    target,
    visible,
  }: {
    target: Element;
    visible: boolean;
  }): void {
    this.renderer.addClass(target, visible ? "active" : "inactive");
    this.renderer.removeClass(target, visible ? "inactive" : "active");
  }
```

```
.artist_image
    height: 0
    padding-bottom: 100%
    background-size: cover
    background-position: center
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    &.inactive
        background-image: none !important
```

the active class gets fired perfectly. But all the background images are still being loaded in the background. Even if they are not displayed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tried it with simple list and it worked for me. Can you please reproduce it in stackblitz?

Comment: I used the package of @Dev Gourav and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazyload-image) that solves the same issue.